# What is the best way to combine and evaluate user input through javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, output, user-input, user-defined-functions

(I'm very new to this, please bear with me) 
I'm making several modules that require user input and I want to somehow combine the input to produce an output. I was thinking of assigning each option a value and adding them together and creating an if/else statement to determine the output...

For example, if the user selects three options with values 1, 2, 3 and the statement says that any combined value greater than 5 will get a result of "Good", then the selected options will get a response of "Good" because when combined, they equal 6 (which is >5). 

Does anyone know a better way, and/or can you direct me to some reference sites that might have what I'm looking for?


Thank you so much!! Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What have done till now,show your code?

Comment: post what you've done so we can actually evaluate it.

Comment: @bigbounty here's my code so far (https://jsfiddle.net/ch889v18/20/)

Comment: @A.Lau here's my code so far (https://jsfiddle.net/ch889v18/20/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<form id="module1">
  <input name="option1" type="checkbox" value="Orange"> Orange
  <input name="option2" type="checkbox" value="Banana"> Banana
  <input name="option3" type="checkbox" value="Apple"> Apple
  <input name="option4" type="checkbox" value="Mango"> Mango
  <input name="option5" type="checkbox" value="Pineapple"> Pineapple
</form>
<button id="evaluate" type="button">Evaluate</button>
<h4 id="result"></h4>
<h5 id="values"></h5>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var scoreConstants = {
            'Mango': 100,
            'Banana': 100,
            'Pineapple': 200,
            'Orange': 50,
            'Apple': 250
        };

        var evalScore = function (selectedValues) {
            var totalScore = 0;
            $.each(selectedValues, function (k, v) {
                totalScore += scoreConstants[v];
            });
            return totalScore;
        }

        var getScoreLabel = function (score) {
            var scoreValue = 'Score: ';
            if (score < 200) {
                scoreValue += 'Average';
            } else if (score >= 200 && score < 500) {
                scoreValue += 'Good';
            } else if (score >= 500) {
                scoreValue += 'Excellent!';
            }
            return scoreValue;
        }


        $('body').on('click', '#evaluate', function (e) {
            var $selectedValues = $('#module1').find('input:checked');
            var selectedValues = [];
            $selectedValues.each(function (k, v) {
                var $selected = $(v);
                selectedValues.push($selected.val());
            });

            var score = evalScore(selectedValues);
            var scoreLabel = getScoreLabel(score);

            var valueString = 'Selected: ';
            if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
                $.each(selectedValues, function (k, v) {
                    if (k === (selectedValues.length - 1)) {
                        valueString += v;
                    } else {
                        valueString += v + ', '
                    }
                });
            } else {
                valueString += 'None';
            }

            var $result = $('#result');
            $result.html(scoreLabel);

            var $displayValues = $('#values');
            $displayValues.html(valueString);

        });
    });
</script>
```

See the code working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/0x2L0dek/1

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Is there a way to assign different values to each input? this (https://jsfiddle.net/ch889v18/20/) is my current jsfiddle. Thank you for replying!!

Comment: I've updated my js fiddle which probably could help you: https://jsfiddle.net/0x2L0dek/1/

Comment: Sorry, do you know if there's a way to combine multiple types of input?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this. 
To see the result, check your console.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value=1>1</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" value=2 class="chk">2</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" value=3 class="chk">3</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" value=4 class="chk">4</input><br>

<button id="button1" onclick="checkSum()">Submit</button>

<script>
function checkSum(){
var chk = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');

sum = 0;
for(var i=0; chk[i]; ++i){
      if(chk[i].checked){
           sum = sum + parseInt(chk[i].value); 
      }
}

console.log(sum);
if(sum > 5){
console.log("Good");
}
}  
</script>
```